# Freezing Issue in Laravel and Bootstrap Application on Chrome Browser

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, deployment, cross-browser, bootstrap-5

I have an application built on Laravel and Bootstrap. It works best on the Safari browser, functions almost correctly on Firefox, but freezes on Chrome. What could be the issue?

In your Stack Overflow question, you can include a section like this to provide information about what you've tried and what you were expecting:

"I've attempted to troubleshoot the freezing issue in my Laravel and Bootstrap application on Chrome browser by:

Clearing browser cache and cookies.
Updating Chrome to the latest version.
Checking for JavaScript errors in the console.
Reviewing my code for any potential compatibility issues with Chrome.
I was expecting these steps to resolve the problem, but the issue still persists. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated."

Comment: How should we guess what is wrong with code we don't know?